# How to reverse the direction of Touchpad two-finger scrolling in Wayland Gnome?

Tags: debian, touchpad, wayland

I cannot find anything in Settings > Mouse and Touchpad for the change. 
My X11 configs do not work here because I am using Wayland.

OS: Linux Debian Stretch 9.1
Gnome: 3.22
Wayland: 1.12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install `gnome-control-center` than open it.

Select `Devices` from the side Navigation bar than 
select `Mouse & Touchpad`.

There you will find the option to toggle `Natural Scrolling`

[image: gnome-control-center]

Comment: I think the term *Natural Scrolling* is confusing. Who has decided that the On option is natural scrolling? - - Turning it off just reverse the direction. I would call it instead **Natural Scrolling Direction**.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just had to:

```
Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Mouse -> Natural Scrolling -> Off
Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Touchpad -> Natural Scrolling -> Off
Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Tap to Click -> On
```

Comment: On Debian 11 I can confirm that I had to change both the mouse and the trackpad settings for my trackpad scrolling to finally be what I wanted.